# Place legend inside the plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I am trying to place my plot legend inside the graph.  Currently it sits outside the plot and gets covered up when I place another plot next to it.

[image]

This is the code I am using.

```
plot1 = Show[{dateListPlot, fitPlot, fitPlot4, fitPlot3, fitPlot2}, ImageSize -> 900];
Legended[plot1, LineLegend[{ Cyan, Purple, Green}, {"21", "14", "7"}, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}]]
histogram = Histogram[values, {2}];
GraphicsRow[{plot1, histogram}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also put your `LineLegend` in an `Inset` on `Prolog` (or `Epilog`) with correct placement (`Scaled` parts for `Inset`):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Prolog ->
  Inset[
   LineLegend[
    (* Default colors acquired awkwardly... *)
    Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 2], {Sin[x], Cos[x]}],
   Scaled[{3/4, 1}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I will try to create a minimal example with some randomly created data:

```
SeedRandom[3]; data = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
plot1 = Legended[
  ListLinePlot[Sort@data, ImageSize -> Medium]
  , Placed[
   LineLegend[{Cyan, Purple, Green}, {"21", "14", "7"}, 
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}], {0.8, 0.8}]
  ]

histogram = Histogram[data];
GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, histogram}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: More straightforward, `SeedRandom[3]; data = Sort@RandomReal[1, {3, 10}]; plot1 = ListLinePlot[data, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> {Cyan, Purple, Green}, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"21", "14", "7"}], {0.65, 0.8}]]`